# Access UserProfile Web service using java in Unix

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, sharepoint-2010

I am facing issue while trying to Consume UserProfile Webservice via java application in unix environment. The exact same code works in Windows environment when tested in Eclipse. But the same throws error as shown below when tested in Centos 6.3 OS.

I have created the Stubs from WSDL and using it. Also the Unix based server is not registered in domain. I am sure it has something to do with the User credentials. But i am not sure on how to pass it to the application.

Java Main Program :

```
import com.microsoft.webservices.sharepointportalserver.userprofileservice.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestWebservice{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            UserProfileService ups = new UserProfileService();
            UserProfileServiceSoap upssoap = ups.getUserProfileServiceSoap();           
            ArrayOfPropertyData userInfo = upssoap.getUserProfileByName("E12345");          
            List<PropertyData> listPropertyData = userInfo.getPropertyData();

        for (int i=0; i < listPropertyData.size(); i++){
            PropertyData tempPropertyData = listPropertyData.get(i);
            System.out.println("tempPropertyData.getName = " + tempPropertyData.getName());
            ArrayOfValueData tempValues = tempPropertyData.getValues();

            List<ValueData> listValueData = tempValues.getValueData();
            System.out.println("listValueData.size()= "+listValueData.size());

            for (int j=0; j < listValueData.size(); j++){
                ValueData tempValueData = listValueData.get(j);
                Object aValue = tempValueData.getValue();
                System.out.println("aValue = " + aValue);
            }//end for j
        }//end for i

    }
}
```

UserProfileService.java (Stub)

```
private final static URL USERPROFILESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException USERPROFILESERVICE_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName USERPROFILESERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService", "UserProfileService");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://SharepointServer/SiteName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    USERPROFILESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    USERPROFILESERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}

public UserProfileService() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), USERPROFILESERVICE_QNAME);
}

public UserProfileService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), USERPROFILESERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public UserProfileService(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, USERPROFILESERVICE_QNAME);
}

public UserProfileService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, USERPROFILESERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public UserProfileService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public UserProfileService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns UserProfileServiceSoap
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "UserProfileServiceSoap")
public UserProfileServiceSoap getUserProfileServiceSoap() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService", "UserProfileServiceSoap"), UserProfileServiceSoap.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns UserProfileServiceSoap
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "UserProfileServiceSoap")
public UserProfileServiceSoap getUserProfileServiceSoap(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService", "UserProfileServiceSoap"), UserProfileServiceSoap.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (USERPROFILESERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
        throw USERPROFILESERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    }
    return USERPROFILESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
}
```

Error in Unix :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://SharepointServer/SiteName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL. It failed with: 
Got Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://SharepointServer/SiteName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL while opening stream from http://SharepointServer/SiteName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:173)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:155)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:221)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:169)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:101)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at com.microsoft.webservices.sharepointportalserver.userprofileservice.UserProfileService.<init>(UserProfileService.java:44)
at JacobClient.main(JacobClient.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://SharepointServer/SiteName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL while opening stream from http://SharepointServer/SiteName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:842)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:283)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:140)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myteamssgp1/sites/PTFApps/FARequest/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1041)
at     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:827)
... 10 more
```

Any guess what extra need to be to get it work in Unix server

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code resolved my issue

```
        Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator() 
    {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("EMPID", "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
        }
    };
```